# Django - Filtering Field In DetailView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

**Hi all,**

I've been building a Django app that allows users to stream and download music. However, there is one issue that I'm having with the artists profile pages; I'm trying to request the songs by the artist only in a DetailView as I'm treating it like a blog system.

Is this possible in a DetailView? Or do I need to make a filter? I've been searching the web for days now and didn't really understand what I can do or how to get the specific data field from the model.

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated!

```
class musicartist(DetailView):
model = MusicArtist
template_name = 'RS_MUSIC/artist.html'

# override context data 
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    context = super(musicartist, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs) 
    # add extra field  
    current_band = MusicItems.objects.all().filter(artist=MusicArtist.title)[:1]
    context["songs"] = MusicItems.objects.filter(artist=MusicArtist.objects.all().filter(title=current_band)[:1])
    return context
```

Comment: How does the url for this `DetailView` look like? There must be some `id`/`pk` in url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. Just needed the following code:

```
class musicartist(DetailView):
model = MusicArtist
template_name = 'RS_MUSIC/artist.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(musicartist, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context_related = MusicItems.objects.filter(artist=self.object.title)
    context['related'] = context_related
    return context
```